# Liferay static url for dynamic data

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I want to serve some data from an static url in Liferay. For example, say to serve a json containing the logged user from "http://server.com/whatever/user" so all the portlets in the proyect can read it. Right now I can do it with a portlet, but then I have to set the url with the configuration panel and I don't like that.

I've seen that I can put jsp files with the static content, but don't know how to access the information of session, users, etc.

Friendly urls seem to accomplish something similar but seem overly complicated and focused in getting a short easy url, something I don't care.

So, how can I get some internal data in an static url (I don't mind if it's friendly, long or short, but always the same) so every element of a Liferay proyect can read  it?

**FOURTH EDIT**: Another way to put it...

In my eclipse I have this tree:

/whatever-war/docroot/html/fancy-porlet/list.jsp

How do I access that jsp in a browser without having to go the Liferay panel and putting the portlet in the menus of the web?

**FIFTH EDIT**: I haven't had the time to research any more, but I have this in my notes...

https://server/language/c/portal/layout?p_l_id=plid

This goes straight to the portlet, sometimes. *plid* comes from

```
PortalUtil.getPlidFromPortletId(themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId(), name_of_portlet_and_war)
```

It's no solution for me because, it doesn't always work. Sometimes you get a numeric identifier, sometimes you get a zero. I'd bet on the name of portlet and war being incorrect so it doesn't find the portlet, but then, how do you find the new name of the portlet? Sadly, I discarded the code where the name came from, but is coming from Liferay.

**SIXTH EDIT**: What I want to do is to be able to call a fixed url, with some data internal to Liferay, and get information based on that data back.

Answer (score 1):

There are several aspects here:

Every portlet already has access to the user through a request attribute called [ThemeDisplay](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/theme/ThemeDisplay.html):

```
ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay) request.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
```

Check ThemeDisplay's interface for the various options that you have in order to get the current user's id or object.

You've asked about JSON delivery - this will need to go through Liferay and not (directly) through a JSP in your individual web application. The reason is that any request processed by Liferay will contain the user's information, but as any proper webapp, it's completely separate from any request directed at another webapp: Unless included by Liferay, your JSP will have a different session that has nothing to do with Liferay's session. (I hope this explanation makes sense)

If you write a servletFilter hook, you might not yet have the portal context initialized (Liferay 6.x has been a while for me, pardon for being vague here). If you're on the portlet side, you might have to do more than you expected.

One option that you have is to embed a portlet on every page, automatically (e.g. when it's deployed, it's available). You can configure a portlet to be automatically included on every page, it's done for the chat portlet, for example. That portlet does not need to have any UI, it just needs to expose its resourceURL, so that you can use it from everywhere.

However, I somehow doubt that you use it, given that every portlet has the information already at hand.
But I might also just not understand all of your requirements...

Comment: I just need the canonical url to a portlet. If I copy paste the url generated by Liferay it works great, but uses the url given by the Liferay Control Panel, which could change without notice, breaking the links.

Comment: There's no canonical "url to portlet". It depends on which page it's on. But you can make its resourceURL available on each individual page, or just use one and provide its name through a common configuration to each portlet. Or just use ThemeDisplay from each portlet.